# Red columns in Phpmyadmin designer?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a question concerning the phpmyadmin designer. In my table there are some columns which are red. What is the meaning of it? It's for sure not that the columns are wrong cause it's a solution given by my professor. It cannot be the indexes as well cause those columns are already connected by lines and they are in a neutral colour.

Would be glad if anyone could help me with this issue.

Regards

Susi Fouani

I've already tried to figure it out by myself and googled it but I did not find a solution at all.

Comment: Funny I googled and bam, there is a Dup on Stackoverflow, first in the search result

Comment: I did, the Duplicate is a link to another question and Answer set here in SO

Comment: In short, colour does not mean anything it is just used for defienition between multiple lines

Comment: Yeah but it's just about the connecting parts in phpmyadmin and not the table itself. I have the problem that my columns in my table are red.

Comment: read the duplicate thats what it is there for

Comment: Thanks I read it but I didn't know that it includes the columns as well. Just thought it's about the connecting part as it is said in the post.

Comment: Cause the connecting arches have different colors as well. And they are blue, yellow and whatever. But the columns of my table aren't so that's why I thought it was a different type of question.